# Use Scala templates from Play! framework in scala.js

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, scala.js

Templates from the Play! framework compile to Scala and seem to be a nice fit for a scala.js project to use for client-side templating. How hard is it to use them in a scala.js project? Since I'm very new to both Scala and `sbt`, detailed instructions would be much appreciated.

Alternatively, is there any other template engine which would be better suited for use with scala.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it will be possible to use Play! templates in Scala.js just yet. The problem is that compiled Play! templates refer to Play! libraries, including

```
import play.templates._
import play.templates.TemplateMagic._
import play.api.templates._
import play.api.templates.PlayMagic._
import play.api.i18n._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
```

These are only compiled for the JVM, and I would be surprised if they can be retargeted at Scala.js trivially.

To manipulate HTML trees in Scala.js, I recommend [ScalaTags](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags). Although not strictly speaking a template library, it can be used to do the same job as a template library.

Comment: Thanks, ScalaTags looks real sweet.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone this [repository](https://github.com/vmunier/play-with-scalajs-example) and start there.